# How to create a dictionary for nested tuple values to calculate the count of data between different timeranges?

Tags: python

I stucked on one query I have a list of timestamps collected as:

```
ts = ['1649081914.478129', '1649075009.809909', '1649071215.209429',
      '1649070953.689649', '1649059574.289319', '1649057731.515459',
      '1649054673.606479', '1648844679.371929', '1648827599.979319',
      '1648789435.095729', '1648764150.271649', '1648754749.161749']
```

I have to create a list of dictionary items for counting the number of `ts` in different time ranges.

eg:

```
start_date = "1/4/22"
end_date = "5/4/22"
```

`IST_TimeRange` is a check on the list of timestamps above to validate if a timestamp value comes under a timewindow defined.

Similarly for other `EU_Timerange` and `US_Timerange`.

A dictionary output should look like as below:

eg:

```
{((1, April, 22), IST_TimeRange): 2,
  (1, April, 22), EU_TimeRange): 4,
  (1, April, 22), US_TimeRange): 2,
  (2, April, 22), IST_TimeRange): 2,
  (2, April, 22), EU_TimeRange): 6,
  (1, April, 22), US_TimeRange): 2,
  (3, April, 22), IST_TimeRange): 2,
  (3, April, 22), EU_TimeRange): 2,
  (3, April, 22), US_TimeRange): 2, ... and so on}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it vice versa.
As dict can hold only primitive values, you can consider dict collisions. I suggest you to use `defaultdict`.
Your dict will look like this:
`d={2: [((1, April, 22), EU_TimeRange), ((2, April, 22), IST_TimeRange)]}`.

```
d: DefaultDict[int, List] = defaultdict(list)
d[<your key(int) value>].append(<your necessary Tuple>)
```

Comment: I need to put this data to CSV so thought of following the same pattern as I have updated above so that I can easily use csv.DictWriter further put data to csv